# can a static class member be private?

Tags: python

Can a static member be private in a python class? 
What is the best practice for calling a getter?
If not, is it a bad practice and why?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "private". Nothing is really private.

Comment: I think it would help if you showed some code demonstrating what you're asking.  Otherwise, the question is to ambiguous for folks to help.  If you haven't seen it, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good resource on how to formulate your question, and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) outlines the acceptable topics for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In python, nothing really is private.

Best practice for anything considered private, is to prefix the member with an underscore; see [What is the meaning of a single and a double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

If you like a getter / setter based approach, check out the [python property decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). However, in my experience, you would typically just have those public members be public (not prefixed with underscore). The typical use case I would use a property for is some calculated attribute (i.e. a method call disguised as an attribute).

Comment: thanks, i understand about underscore prefix and the property decorator, and understand the private notation with underscore. h/e I couldn't write a property decoration for a *static* class member. I would like to get the benefits of the property decoration , on a static member of the class.